# I committed to Lifehacks, but now it has vanished from my profile page

Tags: discussion, bug, area-51

For those who don't believe it:

[image]

[image]

Though it is good for me that now I don't ***have to*** fulfill my commitment, but I'd like to do it so can you bring it back?

Comment: Had the same happen with a different site I committed to, began doubting my sanity

Comment: I think you can only fulfill your commitment in the first 3 or 6 months, can't you? If that's the case, then as LifeHacks is now more than 6 months old, no one can fulfill their commitment, if they haven't already done so.

Comment: It's probably hiding the shame for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely never fulfilled your commitment. As [Energy Numbers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259419/i-committed-to-lifehacks-but-now-it-has-vanished-from-my-profile-page#comment845684_2594190) noted, it likely isn't showing on your profile page since Lifehacks is past the 6 month mark of being in beta, and you never fulfilled the Lifehacks commitment so it doesn't appear under fulfilled commitments. There is no spot for "unfulfilled" commitments that are not longer current commitments, thus you don't see it on profile page.

From the Area 51 [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Once you've fulfilled your commitment on a new site **by asking and answering** a few questions, you'll be able to commit to another site. If you are very active, you may be able to re-use your commitment as soon as the second day of public beta. If you aren't active on the site, you won't be able to re-use the commitment until the end of the public beta, or until six months after the beta began.

It shows that you have [0 answers](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/108/theindependentaquarius?tab=topactivity) on Lifehacks. <strike>To fulfill the commitment you need to answer questions too.</strike> Guess not, since you did fulfill commitment [on health](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/71/theindependentaquarius?tab=topactivity), although you have no answers there.

**TLDR;**
How many questions/answers do you need to do to fulfill the commitment? I have no idea. I know on woodworking.se I have answered 2 questions and asked 2 questions. But I still haven't fulfilled the commitment.

I'm going to assume that only posts with positive scores are counted. So if you post 5 questions and 4 answers but only 1 of your posts has positive score you probably won't fulfill the commitment.

I'm not sure there is anywhere where the exact requirements are outlined in detail. So all you can really do is participate a lot, both asking and answering, writing high quality content and hope you get commitment fulfilled. I think it's probably by design that they don't share exactly how to fulfill commitment.

Comment: But I thought you're allowed to have three commitments at once? From the FAQ: To ensure that commitment is taken seriously, you may only commit to three sites at any one time.

Comment: @Catija not sure what you mean, but yea you're right. If you don't fulfill a commitment, then it stays as a current commitment for 6 months after beta started. But if you fulfill that current commitment it goes under the fulfilled commitments and off of the current commitments.

Comment: You don't have to post answers, you just need enough questions or answers.  The requirement is ~10 for late into public beta, but the threshold is smaller during early stages of beta.  Since the OP is at 7, he didn't make it.